# Rt.auth issue while deploying angular firebase project on Firebase Hosting

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using Angular with firebase database. I am using firebase authentication. It works fine on local environment but show errors on deployment on Firebase hosting.
[image]

I have tried importing AngularFirestoreModule && AngularFireAuthModule but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.